# Delete SQS Queues

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell

I have been tasked with setting up a scheduled task that will do the following

- Get a list of all SNS subscriptions that contain "XYZ" in the Endpoint
- Look up the creation of the referenced SQS queue
- If SQS queue containing "XYZ" in the endpoint is older that 24 hours, delete it

I can get a list of SNS subscriptions filtered on the criteria I need using

```
$SNSSub = Get-Subscription -Region us-east-1
$SNSSub | Where-Object {
    $_.Endpoint -like '*XYZ*'

}
```

I can get the creation date using Get-SQSQueueAttribute but not sure how to put these together to delete what I need to.

Any ideas or pointers?

Comment: Do you have to use Powershell? Are you looking for the Powershell command that deletes an SQS queue?

Comment: Yes, I have to use powershell. I am aware of Remove-SQSQueue but not quite sure how to get the specify the URL from the endpoint. Would it be better to use Remove-SNSEndpoint here?

Comment: Ah OK. By 'delete it' you want to delete the SNS subscription or the SQS queue? What is the business problem here to be solved?

Comment: The endpoint is an SQS queue. So either way could work? These queues are recreated every 24 hours and need to be cleaned up.